# Where should I sell exploration data for the most benefit?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I spend a LOT of time outside the bubble. (Both the Solar bubble and Colonia area.) Sometimes, I'll be out for months at a stretch and come back with tens of millions of CR worth of exploration data to turn in.

It seems like a waste to turn in all my exploration data at one place. Especially when I consider that there are certain stations where my data can earn me unique benefits. Benefits I'm aware of come in the form of advanced-level engineer access or system permits, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are more.

I would appreciate if anyone can provide a list of places to sell exploration data, which provide such unique benefits. Please include the following details for each place:

- Client information

  - Name of the faction or individual the data needs to be turned into
  - Details (system name, celestial body name, station name, and pad size) of a station where the client can reliably be found
  - Location should be outside of permit-locked space, if possible
- Benefit details

  - Type of benefit
  - How the benefit is useful
  - How much data needs to be turned in to reap the benefit (if amount is known)
  - What (if anything) needs to be done after turning in the exploration data to claim the benefit
- Prerequisite information

  - What (if anything) needs to be done to unlock access to the client and/or the station
  - What (if anything) needs to be done to unlock Universal Cartographics at the station
  - What (if anything) needs to be done prior to turning data in, to ensure data is counted towards the goal

A couple examples of things I'd expect to see, just that I can name off the top of my head, are Felicity Farseer/Elvira Martuuk (G5 engineer access) and Sirius Corp (Sirius system permit upon reaching ally status).

Comment: I believe there is a power that gives benefits to explorers, but I haven't played in so long that I don't remember.

Comment: @Rapitor That would be a good addition to the list. But I'm mainly looking for specific locations and minor factions that provide unique perks, like engineering and system permits and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody else is posting information of value, I'll summarize what I've dug up from the [Elite Dangerous Wiki](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com).

### Engineers

Not all Engineers accept exploration data for advancement. Below is a list of those that do, and where to sell. You'll have to unlock the Engineers to G1, by performing their individual task, before you can sell exploration data to unlock higher tiers. More information about unlocking the Engineers can be found on the [Elite Dangerous Wiki](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Engineers).

All bases listed in this section are Planetary locations - you'll need Horizons to access them, and they accept any ship size up to and including Large.

- Felicity Farseer at Farseer Inc. (Deciat 6 A)
- Elvira Martuuk at Long Sight Base (Khun 5)
- Selene Jean at Prospector's Rest (Kuk B 3)
- Professor Palin at Palin Research Centre (Maia A 3 A)
- Lori Jameson at Jameson Base (Shinrarta Dezhra A 1)`*`
- Ram Tah at Phoenix Base (Meene AB 5 D)
- The Sarge at The Beach (Beta-3 Tucani 2 B A)

`*` *Shinrarta Dezhra requires a permit from the Pilots Federation, which is obtained once you reach Elite rank in any category.*

### System Permits

Many systems require a Permit before you can jump to them. Some Permits require you to gain ranks with certain Superpowers, while others are granted upon completing an in-game achievement. Then there's a large number of Permits which are currently a mystery to us - nobody knows how to get them.

Besides all of the above, there remain a number of permits which can be obtained by reaching Allied status with a specific Minor Faction. There's several ways to achieve this, and one of them is to sell a load of exploration data to a station controlled by the Minor Faction in question.

Below is a list of permits that can be obtained through reaching Ally status with a Minor Faction. You will need to seek out a System and Station controlled by the Minor Faction yourself, as game mechanics permit ownership of these to change frequently. [EDDB](https://eddb.io/) is a good resource for this.

- **Isinor**

  - Faction: Chapter of Isinor
- **Terra Mater**

  - Faction: Brotherhood of Terra Mater
  - Note: Rare Goods (Terra Mater Blood Bores) available.
- **Jotun**

  - Faction: Dukes of Jotun
  - Note: Rare Goods (Jotun Mookah) available.
- **Sirus**

  - Faction: Sirius Corporation
  - Note: Home to Engineer, Marco Qwent.
- **van Maanen's Star**

  - Faction: Sublime Order of Van Maanen's Star
- **Peregrina**

  - Faction: Peregrina Aristocrats
- **Luyten 347-14**

  - Faction: Luyten 347-14 Prison Colony
- **Hodack**

  - Faction: Hodack Prison Colony
- **Crom**

  - Faction: Crom Silver Boys
  - Note: Rare Goods (Crom Silver Fesh) available.
- **Pi Mensae**

  - Faction: Pi Mensae Brotherhood
- **LTT 198**

  - Faction: LTT 198 Order
- **Nastrond**

  - Faction: Defence Party of Nastrond
- **Tiliala**`**`

  - Factions: Conservatives of Tiliala, The Black Fleet

`**`*Note: It is possible, though extremely rare, that game mechanics may force Permit control to change hands between Minor Factions. Tiliala is one such case. More details of how this happened are on [Galnet News](https://community.elitedangerous.com/en/galnet/uid/5a057eceda59a26bc40b9828). When in doubt about Permit control, check the [Elite Dangerous Wiki](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Permits).*

Answer (score 1):

Just to add something if you find this helpful.

I just tried this with Selene Jean.

Sell approximately 1.5 Mil worth of exploration data can get you from G1 repututation to G3, just enough to unlock their succeeding engineers. 
Sell 3.5 Mil to G4. 
You need a massive amount of 13 Mil in order to reach G5. But it is a good place to sell to considering you can save your material by raising reputation before you craft anything since it will reduce the number of rolls required.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried Iszi factions, but most didn't work because they require a permit and the sites where are the mission to grant a permit don't allow cartographic data. the permit mission requires allied status, so I'd say exploration data can be used in some engineers.

Edit: Learned how to see station capabilities in inara and managed to use exploration data to acquire permits. thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/323495)

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter, you get the same money everywhere.

What I (and I think many others) do is select a minor faction we want to get good standing with, find a station that faction controls, and sell it there.

A few million in data will get you allied :)

Comment: I'm not interested in monetary advantage. The things I listed in my question, as "examples of things I'd expect to see" are all non-monetary perks.

Comment: @Iszi same thing holds anyway, there's no difference per se between where you sell it. Of course some factions might give system permits when you're allied, but that's the only benefit apart from money and reputation you can gain, and a list of system permits is easily available on the wiki.

Comment: System permits aren't the only kind of benefit. Engineering rank is another one I mentioned. And not all permits or engineers can be earned just by selling exploration data. So, I'm looking for a concise list of only those which can - along with any other, similar perks I might not be thinking of.